# Firebase hosting - Unable to authorize access to project

Tags: firebase-hosting

I'm using `$firebase deploy` to upload my static files to my newly created firebase project, but I get the following error in the command line.

```
Unable to authorize access to project project-1234567890
```

The error message goes on to mention the Firebase CLI is only compatible with the new Firebase Console, which is what I'm using.

I've signed in earlier, so I believe I should have access to the project I've created in the console.

Answer (score 45):

Try running this after you go through your firebase init

```
firebase use --add
```

From there you can select your instance, for example: `your-project-name-instance`

I had the same issue, and running that command and selecting the instance allowed me to do the deploy.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Worked out for me!

Comment: Question, when I try to run that command after my init on my new project, the list of projects are not displayed, even the new one I have just created. Learning firebases has been a nightmare for me so far, when it shouldn't be, it all seems fairly straight forward. (I'd like to hear what you have to say before I create a question.)

Comment: I'm assuming you're already authenticated within the terminal prompt?  Meaning if you signed up with your gmail/google login, it asks  you to authorize and then goes into the browser?  You might have to run firebase login?

Comment: @Matt I tried ur solution but this is not working for me

Comment: @vino what happened? Was there an error? Did you authenticate first?

Comment: @Matt I have done firebase authentication, but still, I receive same error line in cmd as reported by Andrew

Answer (score 17):

I solved my problem with the following steps:

1. I removed .firebaserc.
2. Then I again ran:

   ```
   firebase init
   ```
3. Then I chose my default project.

Comment: In my case I modified `.firebaserc` and removed unnecessary projects

Answer (score 12):

Type these commands:

1. `firebase login`

   > Login with your email that content your Firebase project
2. `firebase use --add

   > Choose the name of your project
3. Now type: `firebase deploy`

Answer (score 12):

You can check firebase-debug.log
In my case, the error was "FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials."

run the following command:-

```
firebase login --reauth
```

then you can use

```
firebase deploy
```

Answer (score 4):

When I tried doing a `$firebase deploy --debug` my upload seemed to work. I'm not sure if this new command arg fixed the issue, or if I needed to wait a certain amount of time after creating the project before performing the deploy.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are logged in into the right account. So use `$firebase logout` out and then `$firebase login` select the correct account and allow CLI.

Answer (score 2):

Authorization issue requires you to permit the currently logged under "Project Overview --> Users and Permissions". This error means that the logged in user does not belong to any of the permitted roles for firebase database in question. You must go to firebase console and add user to a role under Users and Permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I did 
yarn build

and add
 {
  "projects": {
    "default": "xxx",
     "staging": "yyyy"
  }
}

to .firebaserc

not sure which one helped!

Answer (score 0):

**I also facing this issue and fixed now**.

1. I also facing this issue and fixed now.
2. I tried logout, logging but any firebase command showing this same error.
3. I confirmed my user id have full access.
4. I tried firebase cli update **npm install -g firebase-tools** not worked
5. I run **CMD** as **run as administrator it worked for some time. But no longer**;

**Finally, I fixed this issue by delete the .config folder then firebase command is working and new *.config* folder created**

```
C:\Users\DELL\.config
```